# Node async waterfall route with functions split in multiple files

Tags: node.js, express, node-async

I have two functions in separate files that I want to call together in one route using async waterfall.  Having trouble setting up the require, invoking the functions, and passing arguments.  Where am I going wrong?

route.js

```
router.get('/bothFunctions', require('./bothFunctions')
```

bothFunctions.js

```
var async = require("async")
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  var userName = req.user.username
  var oneFunction = require('./oneFunction')
  var twoFunction = require('./twoFunction')
  var asyncFinally = function(err, results) {
    if(err) return res.send(err)
    return res.send(results)
  }
  async.waterfall([oneFunction(userName), twoFunction], asyncFinally)
}
```

oneFunction.js

```
var request = require("request")
module.exports = function(userName, callback) {
  request('/address', function(err, res, body) {
    if(err) return (err, null)
    // do stuff with userName
    return(null, arg2)
  }
}
```

twoFunction.js

```
var request = require("request")
module.exports = function(err1, arg2, callback) {
  if(err1) return("error", null)
  request('/address', function(err2, res, body) {
    if(err2) return (err2, null)
    // do stuff with arg2
    return(null, "success")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your waterfall functions need to change like :
oneFunction.js

```
var request = require("request")
module.exports = function(username){
return function(callback) {
  request('/address', function(err, res, body) {
    if(err) return (err, null)
    // do stuff with userName
    return(null, arg2)
  }
}
}
```

twoFunction.js

```
var request = require("request")
module.exports = function(arg2, callback) {
  request('/address', function(err2, res, body) {
    if(err2) return (err2, null)
    // do stuff with arg2
    return(null, "success")
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ebrahim!  Looks like I also entered the err wrong in the returns.  Appreciate the help there!

Comment: @JasonA You're welcome. There are two problems. 1) Wrong usage of function one. 2) Wrong err params. So if your issue is solved please kindly accept mine as answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had was with async.waterfall.  In order to pass arguments to the first function in a waterfall, you have to bind them with the following:

```
async.waterfall([async.apply(oneFunction, "Name"), twoFunction], asyncFinally)
```